# Regex para php, consultar si una variable tiene 1 mayuscula, 1 minuscula, 1 digito y 8 caracteres como minimo

Tags: php, regex, symfony

Tengo un proyecto en php, soy bastante nuevo programando y nunca toque dicho lenguaje, mi pregunta es basicamente lo que dice el titulo, necesito ver si una variable tiene 1 mayuscula, 1 minuscula, 1 digito y 8 caracteres como minimo
Actualmente tengo este if

```
if(!preg_match('^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,}$', $password)){
    /*
     *
     */
}
```

1. Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:... me da este error
2. Supongo que esa expresión regular no esta bien para php, y no estoy encontrando la manera correcta de hacerlo
3. Primero controlo en HTML `'pattern'=>'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$'`

El control en HTML funciona bien, pero quiero hacerlo en Backend también.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer no estás usando delimitadores para tu regex, es decir debes encerrar tu expresion regex con `/` o `#` o `~`, etc.

> Cuando se utilizan las funciones de PCRE, se requiere que el patrón
>   esté delimitado por delimitadores. Un delimitador puede ser cualquier
>   carácter no alfanumérico, ni barra invertida, ni de espacio en blanco.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
if(!preg_match('/^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,}$/', $password)){
    /*
     *
     */
}
```

Puedes leer más sobre [**Delimitadores en PHP**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias ya funciona, definitivamente voy a leer mas la documentacion de php, me ha un poco encontrar una solucion porque ni sabia que era lo que tenia que buscar, pero ahora entiendo mejor.

Comment: De nada @JavierHeisecke. Si, siempre es bueno revisar la documentación. Saludos y suerte!